# How to create Imageview stack

Tags: android, android-layout, android-imageview

I want to display image view like below where one image will be below other. I'm using Picasso to set image. But it is setting image in entire space whereas I want to set only on the top layer. How to achieve this.

Any help would be appreciated.

[image]

Comment: I think you need to customize `FrameLayout` for this.

Comment: @ADM Can you please give more detail.

Comment: @Ragini i think you want like view like this.https://github.com/aaronbond/Swipe-Deck

Comment: have look [this](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=2078060&seqNum=3)

Answer (score 0):

Use StackView.

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/StackView.html

I've only used a widget application, but I probably think to be able to use it on other scene.